# Unable to read certain inputs of STM32F446RE microcontroller

Tags: c, stm32, microcontroller, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

Everyone, I wanted to take 8 inputs from the STM32F446RE Microcontroller. But I am getting right inputs (1 when not in GND and 0 when in GND) from only 3 pins (PC0, PA0 and PB0) in my Microcontroller. I am getting always 0 for other pins (even it is not in ground). Used the debugging mode too to debug this for 1 week. But I am not getting the right input values. Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something in my code? I am attaching my whole code here. The purpose of this code is to take two 4 group of bits as input and sum the bits and output the summation of bits. (Bit wise summation). Please help me out here. I am starting to think the Microcontroller I got is broken. But I also used 2 microcontrollers to check the error. Same thing happens to both of the microcontrollers.

```
#include<stm32f446xx.h>
#include<math.h>

#define INPUTA0 (GPIOC->IDR & (1 << 0)) //PC0 Input
#define INPUTA1 (GPIOA->IDR & (1 << 0)) //PA0 Input
#define INPUTA2 (GPIOB->IDR & (1 << 0)) //PB0 Input
#define INPUTA3 (GPIOC->IDR & (1 << 1)) //PC1 Input

#define INPUTB0 (GPIOA->IDR & (1 << 13)) //PA13 Input
#define INPUTB1 (GPIOA->IDR & (1 << 14))  //PA14 Input
#define INPUTB2 (GPIOA->IDR & (1 << 15))  //PA15 Input
#define INPUTB3 (GPIOB->IDR & (1 << 7))  //PB7 Input 

void outputCheck(int binarySum[]){

    if(binarySum[0] == 0){
        GPIOB->BSRR |= 0x1000000; //PB8 off
    }

    if(binarySum[1] == 0){          
        GPIOB->BSRR |= 0x2000000; //PB9 off
    }
            
    if(binarySum[2] == 0){
        GPIOA->BSRR |= 0x200000; //PA5 off
    }
            
    if(binarySum[3] == 0){
        GPIOA->BSRR |= 0x400000; //PA6 off
    }
            
    if(binarySum[4] == 0){
        GPIOA->BSRR |= 0x800000; //PA7 off
    }
            
    if(binarySum[5] == 0){
        GPIOB->BSRR |= 0x400000; //PB6 off
    }
            
    if(binarySum[6] == 0){      
        GPIOC->BSRR |= 0x800000; //PC7 off
    }
            
    if(binarySum[7] == 0){
        GPIOA->BSRR |= 0x2000000; //PA9 off
    }
    
    if(binarySum[0] == 1){
        GPIOB->BSRR |= 0x100; //PB8 on
    }

    if(binarySum[1] == 1){          
        GPIOB->BSRR |= 0x200; //PB9 on
    }
            
    if(binarySum[2] == 1){
        GPIOA->BSRR |= 0x20; //PA5 on
    }
            
    if(binarySum[3] == 1){
        GPIOA->BSRR |= 0x40; //PA6 on
    }
            
    if(binarySum[4] == 1){
        GPIOA->BSRR |= 0x80; //PA7 on
    }
            
    if(binarySum[5] == 1){
        GPIOB->BSRR |= 0x40; //PB6 on
    }
            
    if(binarySum[6] == 1){      
        GPIOC->BSRR |= 0x80; //PC7 on
    }
            
    if(binarySum[7] == 1){
        GPIOA->BSRR |= 0x200; //PA9 on  
    }
        
}

double binaryToDecimal(int inputVal[]){
    double ans = 0;
    int powerVal = 3;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        if(inputVal[i] == 1){
            ans = ans + pow(2, powerVal);
        }
        powerVal--;
    }
    return ans;
}

int main(){

    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN;
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOBEN;
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOCEN;
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIODEN;
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOEEN;
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOHEN;
    
    GPIOB->MODER |= 0x10000; //PB8 OUTPUT
    GPIOB->MODER |= 0x40000; //PB9 OUTPUT
    GPIOA->MODER |= 0x400; //PA5 OUTPUT
    GPIOA->MODER |= 0x1000; //PA6 OUTPUT
    GPIOA->MODER |= 0x4000; //PA7 OUTPUT
    GPIOB->MODER |= 0x1000; //PB6 OUTPUT
    GPIOC->MODER |= 0x4000; //PC7 OUTPUT
    GPIOA->MODER |= 0x40000; //PA9 OUTPUT
    
    while(1){
        
        
        int input1Array[4] = {INPUTA0,INPUTA1,INPUTA2,INPUTA3}; // input1
        int input2Array[4] = {INPUTB0, INPUTB1, INPUTB2, INPUTB3}; // input2
        
        // input binary to decimal value
        double input1ToDecimal = binaryToDecimal(input1Array);
        double input2ToDecimal = binaryToDecimal(input2Array);
        // total sum of the input1 and input2
        int ans = (int) input1ToDecimal + (int) input2ToDecimal;
        
        int binarySum[8];
        
        // turning total sum to binary number finally
        for(int i = 0; ans > 0; i++){
            binarySum[i] = ans % 2;
      ans = ans / 2;
    }
        
        //answer
        outputCheck(binarySum);
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hardware register address should be `volatile`.  May not resolve all your issue, but good to add.  [Read here for example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651955/write-data-to-register)

Comment: The title of a post should be a short, 'high-level' and describe the problem/question only.  Phrases like "Am I doing something wrong?" can be written in the post, but not in the title.  A better title would be "Unable to read certain inputs of STM32F446RE microcontroller".

Comment: Take out all the computations and test the ports I/O directly. Make the program as simple as you possibly can, until you are sure how to work it. Go one step at a time, test one thing at a time. Remove all possible confusion as whether your bit manipulation functions are correct, and the I/O operations being correct. For example `double` and `pow(2, powerVal);` is **not** the way to obtain integer powers of 2 and bit handling.

Comment: @WeatherVane the code works fine and gives all correct answers into the output ports if I insert the inputs manually into the arrays. And also I have taken out all the computations and tested the ports individually they do not give the required values. Only the pins with PA0, PB0 and PC0 takes inputs correctly.

Comment: All comparisons of the form `== 1` are incorrect (except for PA0, PB0, PC0). Let's you are testing for PC1 with `GPIOC->IDR & (1 << 1)` then the result will be 2 as the second bit from the right is set. Use `!=0` instead.

Comment: Well some of the inputs work fine now. If someone is in my situation then use GPIOx_PUPDR and set it to pull up (01). Then take the input value as uint32_t variable.

Comment: yes if you expect astate when open circuit then pull up or down internally

Answer (score 0):

If someone is in my situation then use GPIOx_PUPDR and set it to pull up (01). Then take the input value as uint32_t variable.